# Hosting Multiple GeoServer instances on the Same DNS

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I have 2 instances of GeoServer that I am trying to run in the AWS Cloud environment on the same DNS.  I am using Tomcat.

https://testhost.com/geoserver
https://testhost.com/geoserver-archive

The load balancer is working fine, but as you can imagine when I login to /geoserver-archive, I end up on pages that are /geoserver instead of /geoserver-archive.

In GeoServer is there a setting or value where I can set the application root to a location other than /geoserver?

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine, I currently have 5 versions of GeoServer running on my machine:

[image]

So the most likely problem is that your load balancer is being used to route your login and access to your GUI, you need to make sure that it doesn't intercept requests that are not aimed at the WMS, WFS etc endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm still missing something.  If I give server 1 a name server 1 and then try and login to server 2, I end up on server 1.  /geoserver-archive/web/.....login ends up going to /geoserver/web/......   I hope that this makes sense.  Thanks again for any suggestions.

Comment: your load balancer is intercepting the GUI requests that should be going directly to a single machine

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Is there anything in my GeoServer config or tomcat config that I may be overlooking?

Comment: yes your loadbalancer is configured wrong